# tabIndex does not behave properly if I click on any other HTML control in the document

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add tabindex in my html page to control the tabbing behavior, I added tabindex in the desired html controls and while pageload I send the focus to the first control (inp 1).

As long as I doesn't click on any other control the tabbing behavior works as per requirement, but if user clicks on any other control the tabbing behavior breaks.

Code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" tabindex="1" placeholder="inp 1"/></td>
        <td><input tabindex="-1" type="text" placeholder="inp 2"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="inp 3" /></td>
        <td><input tabindex="2" type="text" placeholder="inp 4"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Normal tabbing behavior: **inp 1** -> **inp 4**

If user clicks on any other control, let suppose **inp 2** or **inp 3**, and presses tab afterwards it should go to **inp 4**

Is there any way to so? 
Please help.

thanks

Comment: Probably not with pure HTML. You could use JS to listen for the TAB key and position the focus yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example on how to do with with Javacript/jQuery:

```js
    $("[data-tabto]").keydown(function(e) {
      if (e.which === 9) {
        var target = $(this).data("tabto");
        $(target).focus();
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="inp1" data-tabto="#inp4" placeholder="inp 1"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="inp2" data-tabto="#inp4" placeholder="inp 2"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="inp3" data-tabto="#inp4" placeholder="inp 3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="inp4" placeholder="inp 4"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

add tabindex="-2" to the 3rd input element: e.g.
<td><input tabindex="-2" type="text" placeholder="inp 3" /></td>